# Is there a way to combine multi cases of an integral to a single case?

Tags: integration

I want to solve the integral
$$I=\int_{b_l}^{b_r}\mu(x)dx$$
where
$$\mu(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{x-a_l}{a_m-al} & a_l \le x \le a_m\\[1em] \frac{a_r-x}{a_r-a_m} & am \le x \le a_r\\[1em] 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
with the restriction that $a_l \le a_m \le a_r$ and $b_l \le b_r$.

Since there is no restriction of where $b_l$ and $b_r$ are, I have to determine the result by cases, for example:

if $a_m \le b_l \le b_r \le a_r$ then $I=\int_{b_l}^{b_r}\frac{a_r-x}{a_r-a_m}dx$,

if $a_l \le b_l \le b_r \le a_m$ then $I=\int_{b_l}^{b_r}\frac{x-a_l}{a_m-a_l}dx$,

if $a_l \le b_l \le a_m \le b_r \le a_r$ then $I=\int_{b_l}^{a_m}\frac{x-a_l}{a_m-a_l}dx + \int_{a_m}^{b_r}\frac{a_r-x}{a_r-a_m}dx$,

and so on.

But this is tedious because I still have a long way to apply the result further. Is it possible to find the single-case solution regardless of where $b_l$ and $b_r$ are?

Comment: Use the step function and integrate by parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the notation $x^+=\max(0,x)$, you can rewrite $\mu$ as 
$$ \begin{split}
\mu(x) &= \frac{1}{a_m-a_l}(x-a_l)^+ 
- \left(\frac{1}{a_m-a_l}+\frac{1}{a_r-a_m}\right)(x-a_m)^+ 
\\&+ \frac{1}{a_r-a_m} (x-a_r)^+
\end{split}\tag{1}$$
To see that this works, note that the right hand side of (1) is a continuous function which 
changes the slope at $a_l,a_m,a_r$ by the amounts required of $\mu$.

Indefinite integration of $\mu$ can be done in one line, using $\int x^+\,dx = \frac12(x^+)^2+C$. 
$$\begin{split}
\int\mu(x)\,dx &= \frac{1 }{2(a_m-a_l)}((x-a_l)^+)^2 
\\&- \frac12\left(\frac{1}{a_m-a_l}+\frac{1}{a_r-a_m}\right)((x-a_m)^+)^2 
\\&+ \frac{1}{2(a_r-a_m)} ((x-a_r)^+)^2 +C
\end{split}\tag{2}$$
Finally, plug $b_r$ and $b_l$ into (2) and take the difference: the formula is long, but it works for all cases.